# Insert data into SQL Server with a DbParameter in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax-error, sql-insert

When I'm trying to insert values into SQL Server 2008 R2, I get an error [the syntax error ':']

This is what my define model class:

```
public class Company
{
    [DBField("ID"), DBParameter(":ID")]
    public double ID { get; set; }

    [DBField("CCODE"), DBParameter(":CCODE")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    [DBField("CNAME"), DBParameter(":CNAME")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my query

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO TESTDB.SMSGATEWAY_COMPANY(ID,CCODE,CNAME) VALUES (:ID, :CCODE, :CNAME)";
```

After assigning values using stored procedure method, following execution method is used.

```
public override void ExecuteStiredProcedure(string procedureName, List<StoredProcedureInputParameters> paraList)
{  
    using (SqlCommand sqCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqCommand.Connection = base.DBConnection;
        sqCommand.Connection.Open();
        sqCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqCommand.CommandText = procedureName;

        foreach (StoredProcedureInputParameters p in paraList)
        {
            oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParamenterName, p.Value);
        }               

        sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqCommand.Connection.Close();
        sqCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    }         
}
```

When query is executed, I get an error [the syntax error ':']

Please give a solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggests the colon is not recognized as valid syntax. TSQL uses @-signs as variable prefix.

Try using query:

```
INSERT INTO TESTDB.SMSGATEWAY_COMPANY(ID,CCODE,CNAME) VALUES (@ID, @CCODE, @CNAME)
```

.. and make sure your parameter names in `StoredProcedureInputParameters` also include the '@'-sign as prefix, not a colon. See the [example in msdN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).